# search in document with nested documents and nested atrrays mongodb

Tags: mongodb, nested

I have the documents with the following structure:

```
{
  "address":{
    "building":"1007",
    "coord":[
      -73.856077,
      40.848447
    ],
    "street":"Morris Park Ave",
    "zipcode":"10462"
  },
  "borough":"Bronx",
  "cuisine":"Bakery",
  "grades":[
    {
      "date":{
        "$date":1393804800000
      },
      "grade":"A",
      "score":2
    },
    {
      "date":{
        "$date":1378857600000
      },
      "grade":"A",
      "score":6
    },
    {
      "date":{
        "$date":1358985600000
      },
      "grade":"A",
      "score":10
    },
    {
      "date":{
        "$date":1322006400000
      },
      "grade":"A",
      "score":9
    },
    {
      "date":{
        "$date":1299715200000
      },
      "grade":"B",
      "score":14
    }
  ],
  "name":"Morris Park Bake Shop",
  "restaurant_id":"30075445"
}
```

I need to search documents with the first entry of the array coord in document address that are less than  -95.754168

tried to do

```
db.colect1.find({address: {coord:{$lt:-95.754168}}},{"address.coord":1})
```

or this

```
db.colect1.find({"address.coord.1":{$lt:-95.754168}},{"address.coord":1})
```

(colect1 is the collection storing the documents) without success. In particular the second options surprise me , why it does not work??

An inelegant solution would be

```
db.colect1.find({"address.coord":{$elemMatch: { $lt:-95.754168, $ne: 1000000 }}},{"address.coord":1})
```

But is not optimal since I just want to query the first element in the coord array.

I appreciate any help with this

Answer (score 0):

The following query would get us the expected output:

```
db.collection.find({
    $expr:{
        $lt:[
            {
                $arrayElemAt:["$address.coord",0]
            },
            -95.754168
        ]
    }
},
{"address.coord":1}).pretty()
```

**For Mongo version:3.4.2**

```
db.collection.find(
    {
        $where: function(){
            return this.address.coord[0] < -95.754168
        }
    },
    {
        "address.coord":1
    }
).pretty()
```

Comment: got error "errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $expr". version of mongo : MongoDB shell version v3.4.2. Is there another way of solving this without ussing $expr ?